# Unable to see red status bar when recording in background using AVAudioRecorder

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder, audiounit, avaudiosession

I am trying to record in background. I see a red bar in background when I use audiounit technology. But, I don't see a red bar when I use AV Foundation framework (AVAudioRecorder). I have "App plays audio" in required background modes. Here is the code snippet for AudioSession

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:&error];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error];
```

Code corresponding to AVAudioRecorder

```
// ... url, recordSettings initialized properly
recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSettings error:&error];
if([recorder record] == YES)
    NSLog(@"Started recording");
```

Code corresponding to Audio Unit

```
// Describe audio component
AudioComponentDescription desc;
desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
desc.componentFlags = 0;
desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;
desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

// Get component
AudioComponent inputComponent = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);

// Get audio units
oserr = AudioComponentInstanceNew(inputComponent, &m_audioUnit);
checkStatus(oserr);

// Enable IO for recording
UInt32 flag = 1;
oserr = AudioUnitSetProperty(m_audioUnit,
                             kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO,
                             kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                             1,
                             &flag,
                             sizeof(flag));
checkStatus(oserr);

UInt32 enableOutput        = 0;    // to disable output
AudioUnitElement outputBus = 0;

// Disable output
oserr = AudioUnitSetProperty (
                              m_audioUnit,
                              kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO,
                              kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                              outputBus,
                              &enableOutput,
                              sizeof (enableOutput)
                              );
checkStatus(oserr);

oserr = AudioUnitInitialize(m_audioUnit);

oserr = AudioOutputUnitStart(m_audioUnit);
```

I am running it on iOS 6, iPhone 5. It is not clear to me why the recording status bar is not seen when using AVAudioRecorder. Any suggestions on how to get it?